# How to reach the Sharepoint document center using the graph api

Tags: c#, .net-core, microsoft-graph-api

I'm trying to retrieve a document from our SharePoint document center using the Microsoft Graph.  I'm able to reach our base SharePoint site, but can't seem to drill down to the document center.

Our document center url is `<sharepoint_host>/sites/DocumentCenter`.  I want to be able to view and upload files under `<sharepoint_host>/sites/DocumentCenter/Prospects`.

Tried a combination of things to see if I can reach the DocumentCenter, for example:

```
graphServiceClient
  .Sites["<sharepoint_host>"]
  .SiteWithPath("DocumentCenter")
  .Request().GetAsync()
```

but again can't seem to reach it.  Using the [Microsoft Graph SDK for .NET](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-dotnet).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming `/sites/DocumentCenter` corresponds to tenant site collection and `Prospects` to list/library, [`Site` resource](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/site?view=graph-rest-1.0) could be retrieved by *server-relative URL path* like this:

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/{tenant}.sharepoint.com:/sites/DocumentCenter
```

> Refer [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/site-getbypath?view=graph-rest-1.0) on how to address a site resource by path

To retrieve [`List` resource](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/list?view=graph-rest-1.0) the following endpoint could be utilized:

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/{tenant}.sharepoint.com:/sites/DocumentCenter:/lists/Prospects
```

**Example**

```
var site = await graphClient.Sites["contoso.sharepoint.com"].SiteWithPath("/sites/DocumentCenter").Request().GetAsync();
Console.WriteLine(site.Name);
```